# For $p(x)\in \Bbb{C}[x]$ such that $\int_{0}^{1}p(x)x^kdx=0$ for $0\le k\le n-1$, show that $p(\lambda)=0\Rightarrow \lambda\in [0,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

For a complex polynomial $p(x)\in \Bbb{C}[x]$ of degree $n$ such that $\int_{0}^{1}p(x)x^kdx=0$ for $1\le k\le n-1$, show that $p(\lambda)=0$ means $\lambda\in [0,1]$.

I haven't come by any theoretical direction so far. Since it is a question given in an Introduction to Operator Theory and Hilbert Spaces, I think that approaching Complex Analysis only will be very tedious. The problem is that I can't really tell what of the the course themes it is that I should use. I was thinking Min-Max theorem, Spectral Theory and things in that area of the course syllabus. I still can't see how it can be done; the question seems irrelevant. I would appreciate it if you could give any hint or guide me a little.

Comment: It may be relevant to notice that the integral constraint is equivalent to $$p(x)=\sum_{m\geq n}c_m P_m(2x-1) $$ by the orthogonality of shifted Legendre polynomials. Tricomi's inequalities about the zeroes of Legendre polynomials *should* solve the question.

Comment: I don't understand how you arrive at it. Is there a Theorem you were using here?

Comment: Shifted Legendre polynomials give a complete orthogonal base of $L^2(0,1)$ with respect to the usual inner product $$\langle f,g\rangle = \int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,g(x)\,dx.$$

Comment: Another approach may be to simply write the integral constraints in terms of the coefficients of $p(x)$: the Hilbert (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_matrix ) and Vandermonde matrices are so involved.

Comment: Anyway, the roots of a $p(x)$ fulfilling the integral constraints cannot be always real: if $p(x)$ is a polynomial of such a kind, $p(ix)$ is too. I think we may only deduce that the roots of $p(x)$ lie in $|\lambda|\leq 1$ or something like that.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try to catch up with the Shifted Polynomials. I edited my question ($1\le k\le n-1$). Does it solve the problem? Because the original question does stated $[0,1]$.

Comment: Then the original question is simply wrong, because the integral constraints do not force $p(x)$ to have only real roots. The issue is not with $k$, is with $\lambda\in[0,1]$. The only realistic claim is $|\lambda|\leq 1$.

Comment: $$p(x)=P_n(2ix-1)$$ is a counter-example to your actual question.

Comment: I am so sorry to have excluded such a crucial fact: the degree is $n$. I will edit and add it. Truly sorry if I in any way wasted your time.

Comment: No, it is not crucial. Same counter-example as before.

Comment: As stated, the claim is wrong. $$p(x)=P_n(2ix-1)$$ with $P_n$ being a Legendre polynomial is a clear counter-example: orthogonality holds but not every root is real.

Comment: I guess the real intention indeed was $|\lambda|\le 1$. Something didn't seem logical terminologically, as it would be simply to write "show that the polynomial is real", or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

I think the intended question was something like:

> Given $p(x)\in\mathbb{C}[x]$ with degree $n$, such that $$\int_{0}^{1}x^k p(x)\,dx=0 $$ for every $k\in\{1,2,\ldots,n-1\}$, show that the roots of $p(x)$ lie in the circle $|x|\leq 1$.

We may notice that $p(x)$ has $n+1$ coefficients and we have $n-1$ linear constraints on them, so the space of solutions has dimension $2$. We may also notice that
$$ \int_{0}^{1} x^k\,P_n(2x-1)\,dx = 0 $$
for any $k\in\{0,1,2,\ldots,n-1\}$, with $P_n(x)$ being a [Legendre polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials).
 Another solution is given by
$$ p(x) = \frac{P_{n+1}(2x-1)-P_{n-1}(2x-1)}{x}, $$
so the integral constraints translate into:
$$ p(x) = A\cdot P_n(2x-1)+B\cdot \frac{P_{n+1}(2x-1)-P_{n-1}(2x-1)}{x} $$
and the claim follows from [Turan's inequality for Legendre polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tur%C3%A1n%27s_inequalities), or by bounding the eigenvalues of a [Sturm-Liouville problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%E2%80%93Liouville_theory) associated with the [Legendre differential equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendreDifferentialEquation.html).

Comment: yo have $n$ constraints because you have forget the case $k=0$

Comment: @Hamza: the integral constraints are for $k\in\{1,2,\ldots,n-1\}$ and there are $n-1$ numbers in such a set, not $n$.

Comment: I read in the title that $k=0$ is also a constraints

Comment: @Hamza: then the OP modified the question, look at the comments.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio, Thank you very much for that. Is there, however, a way to avoid the Turan's inequality? It wasn't mentioned anywhere in the course notes...